# How to create a generator function that calls generator functions

Tags: python, generator

Consider the following (non-working) example code:

```
class MyGenerator:
    def test_gen(self):
        for i in range(1,5):
            if i % 2:
                self.foo(i)
            else:
                self.bar(i)

    def foo(self, i):
        yield i

    def bar(self, i):
        yield i**2

g = MyGenerator()
for i in g.test_gen():
    print i
```

This will not work, because `test_gen` has no `yield` and is no longer a generator function. In this small example I could just return the values from `foo` and `bar` and put the `yield` into `test_gen`, however I have a case where that's not possible. How can I turn `test_gen` into a generator function again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop over the results of the delegated generators and yield those:

```
def test_gen(self):
    for i in range(1,5):
        if i % 2:
            for res in self.foo(i):
                yield res
        else:
            for res in self.bar(i):
                yield res
```

If you are using Python 3.3 or up, you'd use the [`yield from` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) to do proper generator delegation:

```
def test_gen(self):
    for i in range(1,5):
        if i % 2:
            yield from self.foo(i)
        else:
            yield from self.bar(i)
```

Both re-introduce `yield` into the function, once again making it a generator function.

Comment: Ha, the Python 3 way is exactly what I was looking for! Sweet and concise. Unfortunately I'm on Python 2.7 :-(

Comment: In this special example, the subgenerator will just yield a simple item before exhausting, so the `yield from` examples are fine. But people using it have to attempt they do yield up to exhaustion of the sub-generators, not a single item - and only after that the controls comes back to the primary generator. (otherwise they would not be distinguishable from a plain `yield`)

Answer (score 0):

why not just:

```
class MyGenerator:
    def test_gen(self):
        for i in range(1,5):
            if i % 2:
                yield next(self.foo(i))
            else:
                yield next(self.bar(i))

    def foo(self, i):
        yield i

    def bar(self, i):
        yield i**2
```